# How to boot from disc on windows xp?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-xp

I recently got an old laptop from school running Windows XP SP3. However I don't have the password and the administrator account is also locked out. I have the boot disc for XP but it doesn't prompt anywhere to boot from disc so I can reinstall the os, also there is no option to boot from disc that doesn't require an admin password. I am stuck and I want to know how to boot from disc on windows XP without admin.

Comment: If the built-in Administrator account is disabled (not locked) then you can gain access to the installation. If it's locked, and there isn't another Administrator account you can access, then you will have to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Knowing make and model of laptop would be helpful

Comment: If you need to access any of the data prior to installing a more modern OS that is still supported and receiving security updates, you can utilize numerous DOS tools that can remove the account passwords.  Google HBCD.

Comment: That is the BIOS and/or Power On password that is stopping you. Mostly these cannot be changed - you need to get the password from the school

Answer (score 1):

1. Start your Laptop and go to BIOS by pressing DEL, F10, F12 or ESC based on the manufacturer
2. Set the first boot device to CD-ROM drive and second device to HDD
3. Insert your Windows XP disk in the drive and boot.
4. The monitor will display a message `press any key to boot from disk`
5. You can now continue with installation

**CAUTION**: If your BIOS is also locked then you may try contacting the manufacturer or you may try detaching the motherboard from the laptop and reconnecting it, that usually resets the BIOS. Else try to get support from the manufacturer or try obtaining Windows password from your University.

Comment: F12 worked for an old Dell Inspiron 8300